# Button must have a tooltip in one of template, but not in the others

Tags: python, html, django

I include the button for different templates (and different divs). There should be a tooltip in one of these divs, but not in the others. How can I do this?
I think I can check the div class in the button (something like {% if div_class=="..."%}), but I do not know how to do this. Is it possible? Maybe I need to check the template name or something else?

first.html

```
<div class="single-card__favorite">
  {% include 'button.html' %}
</div>
```

second.html

```
<div class="card__footer">
  {% include 'button.html' %}
</div>
```

button.html

```
{% load user_filters %}
{% if author|isfavorite:user %}>
  <button class="button button_style_none" name="favorites">
    <span class="icon-favorite icon-favorite_active"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="single-card__favorite-tooltip tooltip">Delete from favorites</div>
{% else %}
  <button class="button button_style_none" name="favorites" data-out>
    <span class="icon-favorite"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="single-card__favorite-tooltip tooltip">Add to favorites</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What language is this in? Doesn't look like raw html.

Comment: i dont think this is pure html, consider adding more tags of the tech (frameworks/libraries/languages) that you are using

Comment: oops, this tags from Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional context to the included template using the `with` clause (Reference: [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include)). So you can pass some variable that will indicate that the tooltip should be rendered:

**first.html**:

```
<div class="single-card__favorite">
  {% include 'button.html' with tooltip="yes" %}
</div>
```

**button.html**:

```
{% load user_filters %}
{% if author|isfavorite:user %}>
  <button class="button button_style_none" name="favorites">
    <span class="icon-favorite icon-favorite_active"></span>
  </button>
  {% if tooltip == "yes" %}
    <div class="single-card__favorite-tooltip tooltip">Delete from favorites</div>
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  <button class="button button_style_none" name="favorites" data-out>
    <span class="icon-favorite"></span>
  </button>
  {% if tooltip == "yes" %}
    <div class="single-card__favorite-tooltip tooltip">Add to favorites</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your URLs are different for each template.

Suppose you have 2 URLs:

```
1. domain.com/url1_bro
2. domain.com/url2_bro
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
{% if 'url1' in request.path %}
   <!--add tooltip html-->
{%else%}
   <!--html button without tooltip-->
{%endif%}
```

Comment: What will happen in this case: "domain.com/url1_bro/url2_bro" or "domain.com/url2_bro/url1_bro"?